# Return plot from a python function to Node.js application

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, express, matplotlib

I have an `Express` Node.js application and a function that use `matplotlib` to generate plot in `Python`.

Is there a way I can call Python functions from my Node.js application and send the `plot` back to Node.js after it has been executed? And send the `plot` to `React` page from Node.js?

I know you can use child process to call the python function and send the data back, but I don't know how to do that for `plot`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Embedding in a web application server (Flask)](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html) example, we know:

> Since Matplotlib 3.1, one can directly create figures using the Figure constructor and save them to in-memory buffers.

So here is the workflow:

React web server => Nodejs server => Python flask server

You can create RESTful APIs to send the plot `buffer`, HTML image, image base64 string, etc. back to the Nodejs server.

Your React web server can send an HTTP request to get this plot data from Nodejs server and render it.